# How to reload a view？

Tags: android, android-view

I fourd "invalidate" couldn't reload the view's style and want to know how to make a "view" to reload their own.

i need a way like "setContentView" but not reload all view.

For example, in "padphone", the display will be change when phone push into pad and get value from "xlarge" folder by use code. But the view does not reload the style from the xlarge folder.

Comment: Can you explain more? What are you doing with your view? what is the code that you are using? Right now is hard to know what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh! i know i couldn't achieve it.

Actually, android is using "Reflection" load Xml convert to attributes. like "inflate".

so, So I can only "setContentView".

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to refresh view when the size of this view changed, [requestLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29)
can do the job.